# Print statements in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Print statements are really useful in debugging dart code in flutter. Anyone know the implications of not removing them from the code in the release version?

Comment: They can hurt performance and will spam the device log.  I recommend using something like [package:logging](https://pub.dev/packages/logging), giving it a callback that prints log messages, and then adjusting your logging level to enable or disable messages by severity.

Comment: Could you please point me in direction to an example for what you said?

Answer (score 7):

As possibly unnecessary I/O, `print`/`debugPrint` statements can hurt performance.  They also will spam the device log.

Additionally, since such statements can be visible to anything inspecting the device log, they can easily leak information that might be better left private (e.g. usernames and passwords).

I recommend using something like [`package:logging`](https://pub.dev/packages/logging) instead.  That way you can provide a callback that uses `debugPrint` but can adjust your logging level to easily enable or disable messages by severity (and could enable additional logging in debug builds).

The `package:logging` documentation provides an example, but tweaking it slightly to have different logging levels between debug and release builds:

```dart
import 'package:logging' as log;

void main() {
  // Log everything in debug builds.  Log warnings (and up) in release builds.
  log.Logger.root.level = kDebugMode ? log.Level.ALL : log.Level.WARNING;
  log.Logger.root.onRecord.listen((log.LogRecord rec) {
    print('${rec.level.name}: ${rec.time}: ${rec.message}');
  });

  // ...
}
```